# Rails has_many through ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries
  has_many :jobs, through: :entries
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job_type
  has_many :entries
  has_many :users, through: :entries
end
```

I've been trying for a while and can't seem to get this. I want to select all the jobs that are assigned to a user (user_id: 1) through entries. Any help would be great.

Note: I've tried

```
Job.find(3).entries
```

but that just returns the entries that have a job number of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other (current) answers require at least two database queries. This should give you what you want in one:

```
Job.joins(:users).where(users: { id: 1 })
```

Comment: Perfect, works great! Thanks so much (and to Steve and Jack as well)

Answer (score 1):

Does `User.find(1).jobs` give you what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
u = User.find(1)
what_you_want = u.jobs
```